# Icon in footer not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a footer where I want to position an icon at the right side inside it. The icon is 36 pixel in width and height. It's inside a `div` container with padding of 7 pixel.

From my calculations the icon should be vertically centered, but it's not.

I want the icon to have the same padding on the top, bottom and right side.
What am I doing wrong?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey1588u5/)

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" class="pageheader"></div>
<div data-role="footer" class="pagefooter">
    <div class="info-icon">
        <a class="info-anchor" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; text-shadow: none; color: #ffffff;">
            <img class="info-img" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v1/icons/svg/ic_info_outline_black_36px.svg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.info-icon {
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.info-anchor {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    padding: 0;
}
.info-img {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
}
[data-role="header"], [data-role="footer"] {
    height: 50px !important;
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-role="footer"] {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `display:block` to your `.info-img` otherwise it gets extra bottom spacing (images are `inline` elements by default).  You may also want to add it to `.info-anchor` so it covers the full image

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey1588u5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is 36x36 but `.info-anchor` is 36x17 and is throwing everything off. Add:

```
display:block;
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
```

to .info-anchor and it should appear centered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another method:

Give your **.info-icon**-class the same height as your footer.
Then simply add the following lines:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Added for Browser-Support */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Added for Browser-Support */
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This allows you to move the Icon in the Container itself like we do in the following code, without expanding it:

```
padding-top: 5px;
```

Here is an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey1588u5/1/

I hope I could help you out!
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

`.info-anchor` is only rendering at 36px*17px - if you add

```
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
display:block;
```

To the element it works correctly

```css
.info-icon {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.info-anchor {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  padding: 0;
  /*New Styles Here */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: block;
}
.info-img {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
[data-role="header"],
[data-role="footer"] {
  height: 50px !important;
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-role="footer"] {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="header" class="pageheader"></div>
<div data-role="footer" class="pagefooter">
  <div class="info-icon">
    <a class="info-anchor" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; text-shadow: none; color: #ffffff;">
      <img class="info-img" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v1/icons/svg/ic_info_outline_black_36px.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also achieve the same effect by simply specifying width and height for your `.info-icon` element

```
width:36px;
height:36px;
```